# ImageMagick not renaming output files

Tags: rename, imagemagick

I would like to rename files with ImageMagick and save them in `C:\index\pictures`.

The new file name should consist of the old one (without extension) + org.

I wrote the command line:

```
C:\Programme\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16\magick mogrify -path C:\index\pictures -set filename:f “%%t_org” *.tif
```

but there is no change of the output file name.
What went wrong?

Thanks you for your answers, 
I tired
convert *.tif -set filename:f %t_org %[filename:f].tif 
and it wors well, but I need to rename all images separatly and "convert" put them all together in one file.

Comment: Try putting the `-Path` as a different director than the one the source files are in like a new sub directory you create beneath. I don't have time to test and write a script now but start with using a different path with the `-Path` option to start for a potential simple solution.

Comment: Tag me back with a reply for an update on this.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, [mogrify](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) modifies files by overwriting while [convert](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) creates a copy.

> This tool is similar to convert except that the original image file is *overwritten* (unless you change the file suffix with the -format option) with any changes you request.

To create new files with your naming scheme and using `convert`:

```
convert *.tif -set filename:f '%t.org' '%[filename:f].tif'
```

This command creates new files in current working directory with filename appended by `.org`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to rename a lot of files wich are all in one directory.

Comment: If you only want to rename, perhaps you should consider another tool (such as rename on windows https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490987.aspx ).

Comment: test1.tif to test1_org.tif; when I am using cd \temp\bildgroesse
rename C:\temp\bildgroesse\* *_org it ends with Test2.tif_org

Comment: `rename *.tif *_org.tif`

Comment: (I have tried before) the same result: test1.tif_org.tif

Comment: From  rename documentation: _"You can use wildcards (* and ?) in either file name parameter. If you use wildcards in filename2, the characters represented by the wildcards will be identical to the corresponding characters in filename1."_. You need to match the wildcard with the part you wish to keep unmodified (and change the non-wildcard part accordingly).